# Spring boot multi module project: Unable to add yaml property file from dependency module into main application classpath

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I am building a fairly simple multi module Spring boot application.
My main module is war, while the dependency module is a simple jar (couple of service classes and yaml property file in src/main/resource folder).

When I deploy my main war application, I don't see Spring boot reading or loading the yaml property file from my dependency jar. I do see it reading application.yaml from my main war application.

In my first attempt, i named both the property files (in War and Jar modules) as application.yaml. I tried renaming the Jar module's yaml file module-application.yaml just to make sure, Spring boot is not overriding the entire file.

What's not working for me is property/config  class file in my jar module
Here is a sample class

```
@PropertySource("classpath*:module-application.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="module.orders.urls")
public class SmartApiUrls {

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    private String saveUrl;
    private String getUrl;
    private String cancelUrl;
    private String barcodesUrl;
---
}
```

The properties for this config bean are controlled by the dependency jar and this class is defined by Module jar. The main war application doesn't need to know about this. The main application war has it's application.yaml properties

Any help would be great. I am on Spring boot 2.0 and Java 8
Note: Jar module is just a simple service with no main class. It's not executable on it's own. This jar module is a dependency within the main web application. However, jar has it's own yaml property file with name 
module-application.yml in it's src/main/resource folder.
Thanks
Sri

Comment: Were you able to solve this. I am having a similar issue of figuring out accessing yml files of the main app in the dependent modules